# Isolated Storage always empty on emulator?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've got a Windows Phone 7 Silverlight app that I am trying to use Isolated Storage on the emulator, to no avail. I've got several files added to the project as Content, I've deployed the app to the emulator before launching the debugger, I use the back button to "close" the debugging session, and I do not close the emulator between runs. And every single time, I have empty isolated storage. What am I doing wrong? I use this, comes up blank every time.

```
private void CheckIsolatedStorageForContent()
{
    using ( var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication() )
    {
        foreach ( var fileName in isf.GetFileNames() )
        {
           listBox.Items.Add( fileName ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should also mention, I have also used the Isolated Storage Explorer and confirmed there is nothing but a single folder (Shared), none of my files. But the images display fine in the application, I just can't see any files in isolated storage, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting them in your XAP as content won't deploy them to Isolated Storage.

On the first execution of your app, you'll need to copy the files to the Isolated Storage.  If they're static, there's really no need to do this, as you can just access them as content.  If you need to update them, then you will need to get them to the IsoStore.

Comment: I had no idea (obviously) that I had to copy them first, I was assuming they would be present if marked as content, my bad. Thanks!